# 'Eventing' namespace does not exist in 'System.Diagnostics' in .NET Core and Mono on nix*es

Tags: c#, linux, macos, mono, .net-core

I'm currently developing a C# application that can read and query Windows Event Logs using the following import:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
```

This import worked fine on my Windows 10 laptop using Visual Studio 2017. However, I got the following error running this import on `dotnet run` and compiling this on `mcs`:

```
Program.cs(3,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Eventing' does not 
exist in the namespace `System.Diagnostics'. Are you missing an assembly 
reference? Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I've tried the compilation on Mac OS X laptop and the [mono Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mono/). It seems like it should work on Mac and Linux since I found the code on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Diagnostics/Eventing/Reader). Anyone have a clue? I have been trying to find a `dll` or an import to make this work, but no success so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for my understanding: why do you want to query Windows logs on Mac or Linux?

Comment: You linked to "Microsoft's Reference source" within the Mono repo, that does not mean it is x-plat code...and it is not. Window's Events are not available on Linux/Mac

Comment: @dymanoid the Windows logs are stored in ZIP files and uploaded to application servers for further processing. The servers will run on Linux servers, and it would be nice to use built-in solutions to parse Windows logs instead of delegating the tasks to other compute nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That part of .NET Framework has not been ported into .NET Core 2.0. It is currently in implementation. See: [Port System.Diagnostics.EventLog to .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/24344) which is a part ongoing effort to bring more of System.Diagnostics namespace into .NET Core. EventLog will be shipped in v2.1.0.

I do not know the specific version in which `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` will be shipped.

`System.Diagnostics.EventLog` is redirected to `syslog` on Linux. Reading of logs should be supported as well

Comment: Thanks for the additional context! I posted a comment in the issue you referenced and [another issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12260) to see what the plans are for `Eventing`