# Reading from eventlog. Error: The type name 'EventLog' could not be found in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, event-log

I am trying to read from the eventlog using visual studio 2019. I choose Console App(.NET CORE) for the project type. I use the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string eventLogName = "System";

           EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
           eventLog.Log = eventLogName;

           foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("{0}\n", log.Message);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

> CS1069. The type name 'EventLog' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics.'This type has been forwarded to assembly.This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915998/eventing-namespace-does-not-exist-in-system-diagnostics-in-net-core-and-mon?rq=1

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog NuGet package, version 2.2.0? It works for me with that package. (I'm using .Net Core 2.2)

Comment: Matthew Watson how do I install the package?

Comment: Project | Manage NuGet Packages... -> Browse -> Search for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog -> Select it and click install.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install a **System.Diagnostics.EventLog** Package.

You can Search & install this package ***System.Diagnostics.EventLog*** via Nuget Package Manager or you can install via cli https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.EventLog/.

If you want to know in more detail go through this link [GitHub Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/24344)

I hope, your issue will resolve.